# Initializing database in the base image of a running container

Tags: mysql, initialization, docker, containers

I pulled a mysql:5.5 image from the docker repo which I am using as a base image for my containerized app. After running this application that uses the mysql from the base image, it gives the following error

error: database is uninitialized and MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD not set
  Did you forget to add -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=... ?

How can I make sure that mysql is running on "localhost:3306" on the application container and that it is correctly initialized?

EDIT:
Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql+java+ubuntu_baseimage:latest

# Copy the fat jar inside the image
COPY shaded_jar      /some/location/on/image/app.jar
COPY config.yml      /some/location/on/image/config.yml

 ## What to run when the container starts
#ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/some/location/on/image/app.jar", "server",    "/some/location/on/image/config.yml"]

 #Ports used by this image
 EXPOSE 8080 (http port of the app)
```

Note that the container exposes both 8080 and 3306(mysql) port. But not sure how to connect to this database using 'ocalhost:3306" in the same container?

Comment: can you show a reproducer or your Dockerfile and the commands used to start the container?

Comment: this Dockerfile isn't going to start any MySQL database. Are you sure you wouldn't be better off using a separated Docker container just for the MySQL database?

Comment: I guess I am not clear with that, I wanted to be resourceful by having the app image build from the dependencies( java, maven, mysql etc) and then  point to the localhost for database connection. Is this a possibility? Can there be multiple commands in the entrypoint?